# How can I configure the number of vBuckets on Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

This [document](http://www.couchbase.com/sites/default/files/uploads/all/whitepapers/Technical-Whitepaper-Couchbase-Server-vBuckets.pdf) from Couchbase says:

> The hashing function used by Couchbase Server to map keys to vBuckets
>   **is configurable – both the hashing algorithm and the output space** (the total number of vBuckets output by the function).

However, I did not find any way to configure it. In particular I'm interested in the number of vBuckets, not the hashing algorithm. Could someone please help.
Thank you!

Comment: I would not recommend changing the number of VBuckets and the reason that you aren't finding anything in the documentation is because we don't recommend doing this. Can you add tell me why you want to do this?

Comment: My problem is that rebalancing of empty buckets is very slow (a few minutes per bucket). I noticed that during rebalancing every vBucket is processed and that probably involves some overhead on top of moving the actual data (which is 0 in my case). I thought that by decreasing the amount of vBuckets I could speed up the rebalancing procedure. I need it only for an automation demo where servers are added and removed on the fly and I don't want it to take too long. So my root problem is slow rebalance. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the rebalance to go faster, you don't need to change the number of vBuckets itself, you can just change the number of vBuckets moved concurrently during the rebalance. By default, rebalance moves 1 vBucket at a time.

Here is how you can change this setting: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Tasks/rebalance-behind-the-scenes.html

If you have views defined, you can also disable consistent view querying for the duration of the rebalance to speed it up. Remember to turn it back on after the rebalance finishes! http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-cluster-disable-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately changing the settings did not result in any visible improvements in rebalancing time. I'm using Couchbase v3.0.1